# How could i download a dataframe after performing some calculations on it , with the new result?

Tags: pandas, data-science, data-analysis, google-colaboratory

Link: https://gist.github.com/dishantrathi/541db1a19a8feaf114723672d998b857

Input was a set of date ranging from 2012 - 2015, and need to count the number of time a date repeated.

After counting, I have a dataset of dates and counted the unique counts of each date and now I have to download the unique count with the corresponding date in Ascending Order.

The output file should be in csv.

Comment: `and now I have to download the unique count with the corresponding date in Ascending Order.` - can you explain more?

Comment: Or need `df.groupby('Date').size().reset_index(name='count').sort_values('count')` ?

Comment: as you have seen the last output of counts corresponding to dates, I need to download the last output.

as 
Date -> Count

Comment: .reset_index(name='count') , what does it does in simple language?

Comment: it create 2 column DataFrame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) for 2 column `DataFrame` from `Series`, sort by [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby('Date').size().reset_index(name='count').sort_values('count')
```

Another solution with [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df1 = (df['Date'].value_counts()
                .rename_axis('Date')
                .reset_index(name='count')
                .sort_values('count'))
```

---

```
print (df1.head())
           Date  count
66   02-05-2014     54
594  13-05-2014     56
294  07-02-2014     57
877  19-04-2013     58
162  04-05-2014     59

df1.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: You are welcome! Thank you for accepting. You can upvote too - click to small triangle above `0` above accepting mark. Thanks.